# VBA to export rows from source doc to an existing document and save as new file

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a vba code to open an existing spreadsheet and populate the first row of that existing spreadsheet with the row of the information from the source spreadsheet then auto save it as the project name listed in a specific cell of the source.

Can anyone help me out. I am not a coder, just copying codes that I have found. I am using this code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo PROC_ERROR

Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook, NewBook As Workbook
Dim ThisWorksheet As Worksheet, NewWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, ExportCount As Integer

Set ThisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ThisWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ExportCount = 0

For i = 2 To Aslong
    If ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Open("F:\DBA\Land Opportunities\Set-Up Templates\FOR SALE TEMPLATE.xlsx")
        Set NewWs = Existing.Sheets("Project")
        For j = 2 To 13
            If ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                NewWs.Cells(1, 1) = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Next j

        With NewBook
            .Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
            .Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
            .Title = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 3)
            .SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 3) & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        End With
        ExportCount = ExportCount + 1
    End If
Next i

PROC_ERROR:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "This macro has encountered an error and needs to exit. However, some or all of your exported workbooks may still have been saved. Please try again." _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbInformation
    ExportCount = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "Successfully exported " & ExportCount & " workbooks!", vbInformation
    ExportCount = ExportCount
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not a coder either but I study the code I find and modify it to my needs.

Comment: Do you want this code translated into Apps Script code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something more like this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook, NewBook As Workbook
    Dim ThisWorksheet As Worksheet, NewWs As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, ExportCount As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ThisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ThisWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ExportCount = 0

    i = 2
    While ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Open("F:\DBA\Land Opportunities\Set-Up Templates\FOR SALE TEMPLATE.xlsx")
        Set NewWs = NewBook.Sheets("Project")
        For j = 2 To 13
            If ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                NewWs.Cells(1, 1) = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Next j

        With NewBook
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
            .Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .Title = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 3)
            .SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 3) & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        End With
        ExportCount = ExportCount + 1
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I got rid of a bunch of confusion.  Once you see where your errors can occur you can put error trapping back in if you so desire.

I don't know if this does what you want, but the other thing surely wasn't going to work since `For i = 2 To Aslong` is broken, 'Aslong' isn't set to anything.  Also, `Existing.Sheets("Project")` isn't anything, since `Existing` isn't an object.  You also dimmed a `k` variable that you never used.

Comment: Thank you @n8. however when I try that code, it gives me an error message of "Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range"

Comment: On which line does it fail?

Comment: I am sorry, it does not tell me.

Comment: If you hit "debug" it highlights the line that is throwing the error.  If you hit "end" it just stops the running code.

Comment: ok, it highlighted the sub button1_click() but now it says application defined or object defined error

Comment: I didn't instantiate or iterate the `i` variable.  Try that new code.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response (weekend). I am finding that when I run this code, it is not saving the information i need in the document template I want.

Comment: F8 lets you step through the code.  Hovering the mouse  over variables tells you where the code will save.  `ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 3)` is the name of the file, and NewBook is what is being saved.